# Passing argument of javascript function to java code

Tags: javascript, dojo, slider

I am creating a GUI using dojo slider. Beside the slider there is a text box which will be used to display the current value of the slider.

What I want is that each time the slider is slided, the current value of the slider appears on the text box. Next, this value will be used in further calculation and the result will be displayed on another textbox.

What I have been doing is: inside the dojo slider, I call a javascript function which passes the current value of the slider.

Inside the javascript function, I want to pass the argument of the function into a java code inside the function. The argument will be used by the java code to do a calculation.

My problem is that I could not pass the argument to the java code. My question is how can I do that?

Below is the coding I have written:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.form.Slider");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");

dojo.ready(function(){
var slider = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
 name: "slider",
 value: dojo.byId("walluvalueinit").value,  
 minimum: 0,     
 maximum: 1,    
 discreteValues:11, 
 intermediateChanges: true,
 style: "width:300px;",
 onChange: function(value){
   dojo.byId("walluvalue").value = value;
   changewalluvalue(value);  //CALLING FUNCTION changewalluvalue()
 }
}, "slider");
});

</script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
<jsp:useBean id="beanAnalysis" class="bean.Analysis" scope="application"/>

<script>
function changewalluvalue(value){
<%
ExteriorUnheatedGroundLossCalculation eug = new ExteriorUnheatedGroundLossCalculation();

    //MORE CALCULATIONS
    //SET U VALUES PROPERTY IN ExteriorUnheatedGroundLossCalculation
    eug.setWallUValue(value); //THE ARGUMENT "value" SHOULD BE PASSED HERE

====more java code=====
%>
}
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
  <td width="150">Wall U Value</td>
  <td width="411" align="center" valign="middle"><div id="slider"></div></td>
  <td width="154" align="center" valign="middle"><label for="walluvalueinit"></label>
      <input type="text" name="walluvalueinit" id="walluvalueinit" value="${beanAnalysis.wallUValue}"/></td>
  <td width="152" align="center" valign="middle"><label for="walluvalue"></label>
      <input type="text" name="walluvalue" id="walluvalue" /></td>
</tr>

<td colspan="2" align="center">Transmission Loss</td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle"><label for="transmissionlossinit"></label>
      <input type="text" name="transmissionlossinit" id="transmissionlossinit" value="${beanAnalysis.transmissionLoss}"/></td>
  <td align="center" valign="middle"><label for="transmissionloss"></label>
      <%--CALCULATION RESULT WILL BE DISPLAYED HERE--%>
      <input type="text" name="transmissionloss" id="transmissionloss" /></td> 
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you'll need to use AJAX to pass the value to your Java code. I guess Dojo has some utilities for that. You'll also need to instrument your Java code to deal with the requests and to perform the actual logic.

Comment: One question: how can I pass the response from jsp to the ajax caller? 
From AJAX tutorial, I find that asp will use: 
response.expires = -1 
response.write(value)

And php uses:
$responses = $value;

But I did not find example for jsp. Can you show me how to do it in jsp?

Comment: Hi. I don't really use JSP. The principles are pretty much the same everywhere, though. You might want to check out some JSP specific tutorial such as this: http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=580 . Adapt that to work with Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because client-side JavaScript in a JSP cannot call server side Java methods. You have two options: (1) implement your calculation in JavaScript instead, or (2) do an Ajax call to a server-side service that performs the calculation.

Comment: Thanks @cebarett, I think I'll try using JavaScript first.

Comment: One question: how can I pass the response from jsp to the ajax caller? 
From AJAX tutorial, I find that asp will use: 
response.expires = -1 
response.write(value)

And php uses:
$responses = $value;

But I did not find example for jsp. Can you show me how to do it in jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation code should be a regular servlet, designed specifically to do the logic/calculations you require.  JSP pages are best for providing HTML and/or direct renderable content.

Remember, once the page is served, any javascript on the page is executed on the client/browser.  You no longer have direct access to Java structures.  You must use AJAX to communicate back to the server.  Have the servlet you invoke return a JSON object containing the results of the calculation.

On the client-side, use dojo.xhr (Get or Post version) and set the handleAs property to 'json'.  For example:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
  // URL to servlet that will do computation for us on the server
  url: url_to_calc_servlet,

  // Tell Dojo to handle return value as a JSON string, so dojo will
  // auto-convert it into an Object.
  handleAs: 'json',

  // Specify request parameters to servlet as an object of
  // name/value pairs.
  content: {
sliderValue: XXX
  },

  // Define callback function for dojo to call when servlet returns
  load: function(response) {
    // response will be the object your servlet returned
    // ... access response data and update page accordingly...
  }
});
```

Check the Dojo documentation for more information about dojo.xhr.

Comment: actually, I have solved this problem by using servlet. but I used different approach than yours. thanks anyway @ewh.